# java DecimalFomat in C#

Tags: c#

I have these code which I have converted from Java. Now I need to change this DecimalFormat in C# Syntex.

```
private string formatValue(double dVal)
        {
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
            df.applyPattern("######.###");
            DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            dfs.DecimalSeparator = '.';
            df.DecimalFormatSymbols = dfs;
            return df.format(dVal);
        }
```

Kindly help me to do the same.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `number.ToString("######.###")` to achieve the same in C#

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

```
var nf = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();
nf.NumberDecimalSeparator = "-";
double d = 123456.789;
d.ToString("########.###",nf);//prints 123456-789
```